# AWS EKS EC2 node memory calculations for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, kubectl

Is there a more comprehensive (or simpler) kubernetes calculator or explanation than the [learnk8s.io one hosted here](https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-instance-calculator#what-s-the-maximum-number-of-pods-in-eks-)? I've been studying and reading K8S documentation for days and I'm still not fully sure I understand all the component relationships correctly.

I'll use a specific instance type for math purposes but I'm more focused on trying to understand the underlying mechanics.

I have an AWS EKS cluster of EC2 nodes. Assume each EC2 node is a 32.0 GiB, 8 vCPU instance. Assume 3 running nodes.

If I run: `kubectl top nodes`

I see node A:

```
NAME                          CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
ip-10-1-x-xxx.ec2.internal    196m         2%     8726Mi          28%
```

Which is the actual usage to the VM (node).

if I run command: `kubectl describe node ip-10-1-x-xxx.ec2.internal`

kubectl returns:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests           Limits
  --------           --------           ------
  cpu                5985m (75%)        6903m (87%)
  memory             25912486801 (81%)  30038891665 (94%)
```

Where I can see that my node contains several pods (kube-system, nginx-ingress), but largely it's the application pod with:

```
 Namespace                                 Name                                                        CPU Requests  CPU Limits   Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                                 ----                                                        ------------  ----------   ---------------  -------------  ---
  z3f2445f2                       app-z3b4e2430-qnkb7               4200m (53%)   4200m (53%)  20000Mi (65%)    20000Mi (65%)  2d3h
```

So primarily it's the CPU limits and resource limits taking up most of the node memory, along with memory usage from the other pods and eviction threshold (which is..?).

If typical actual usage on a node is 8-10 GiB, and the node (instance) capacity is 32.0 GiB, how should you think about resource limits or memory commitments in between? What is a reasonable buffer? Is it correct that the memory (resource) request defines the number of pods (instances) possible to be scheduled per node? For example, if I want to run 3 instances of an application on a node, if that app is 8-10 GiB, then I can't scale or auto-scale to more than 3 instances, because 4 * 8 GiB = 32, which exceeds my instance memory (similar principle would apply to CPU). Or if I have 3 application instances and 3 nodes will they be auto-allocated across my 3 nodes so technically I could run up to 3 * 3 instances (pods) and not consume all my memory? Which understanding is correct or incorrect? thanks

Example application instance replicas:

```
NAMESPACE                                  NAME                                                              CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)               
z3f2445f2-app                        app-z3b4e2430-6gckt                     5m           4429Mi          
z3f2445f2-app                        app-z3b4e2430-6nrmh                     5m           4423Mi          
z3f2445f2-app                        app-z3b4e2430-9cqwx                     11m          4422Mi
```